# Rails Resource controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Newbie question:

(Apologies if this had been already discussed somewhere. I did try searching for but did not find the info)

The Route file defines the following resource:
**resources :photos**

Per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default the above statement will  define 7 routes corresponding to HTTP verbs. 
All good till now!
But no method other than "**show**" is defined in the PhotosControllers class.

**My Confusion is**: As none of the other methods (index/create/edit/destroy/..) are defined in the controller class, if the user types in /photos/new or /photos, etc. **which method(s) will handle these request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually these requests won't be handled by any method, rails will search/try to use an `index` method in the controller if a user make a request with `/photos` for example, if these methods aren't defined you'll have an exception and a 500 error, as you correctly thought.

EDIT:

As Olivier mentioned, if you want just the `show` event you can pass more param to `resources` route, like

`resources :photos, only: :show` or

`resources :photos, only: [:show, :index]` or even

`resources :photos, except: [:new, :create]`

Comment: This is the correct answer. To answer something OP may wonder then, those routes can be disabled : `resources :photos, only: :show`

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks Miguelgraz, Rajesh and Oliver!

Answer (score 2):

Lets take the example of `PhotosController#new` action.

If you have NOT defined the `new` action your controller AND you have NOT defined the `new` view, you will get an error, such as:

```
Error: The action 'new' could not be found for PhotosController
```

However, if you have NOT defined the `new` action BUT you have a new view file in `views/photos/new.html.erb`, the page is rendered with that file

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses the convention over configuration software design paradigm, which means it has a way of doing things unless you override them. In this case, rails will render `new`, `index`, `show` and `edit` views if they exist, even if you have not defined the actions on your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use custom way.

```
get 'export/devices' => 'export#devices'
match 'update_company_status' => 'companies#update', via: [:put]
```